# Possible tag-synonym: jslink / csr

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The "client side rendering" feature of SharePoint 2013 is sometimes called CSR and sometimes JSLink.
There is a [csr]-tag and a [jslink]-tag in use.

I suggest we create a [client-side-rendering]-tag and synonym it [csr] and [jslink].

Answer (score 2):

I think [client-side-rendering](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-side-rendering) and [jslink](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jslink) should co-exist because not all CSR is JS Link. Possibly we could make [csr](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csr) a synonym of [client-side-rendering](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-side-rendering), but not specific frameworks. There are other framework which could accomplish CSR, and I like the possibility to specify framework as a tag.

The synonym have been created: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-side-rendering?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: To me CSR is more than JSLink as well, we have for example Display Templates for Search as another CSR technology

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to introduce `[client-side-rendering]` tag.

Sometimes I find it very confusing when the question is tagged with [JSLink]. Since [JSLink] is a web part property, it is supposed to be related with applying
the rendering templates via web parts questions.

`[csr]`& `[client-side-rendering]`  are more broad tags since it is a new way to customize list and forms in SharePoint 2013 in addition to XSLT. JSLink property could be considered just a private case of CSR.